# Get superclass field value using JQPL query in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, jpql

Let's say I have a superclass called Vehicle like this:

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    private LocalDateTime dateTimeOfCreation;
}
```

And, let's say I have a subclass called Car like this:

```
    @Entity
    public class Car extends Vehicle{
    }
```

And, I have a I want to select all cars that are created after some date. And, although `dateTimeOfCreation` field is in superclass, I need to be able to query the subclass for the reason that is not easy for me to explian.

I tried this query: `SELECT c from Car c WHERE c.dateTimeOfCreation > :dateTime`

However, I get an ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier error, which is in some way logical because the class car doesn't have that field and Cars. Also, I am using a JOINED INHERITANCE, so every class has it's table and `dateTimeOfCreation` is stored in Vehicle table. That's something I can't change, again for the reason hard to explain.

EDIT: The code I gave is just an example. In reality. The Vehicle is a part of a framework that I shouldn't change, so it already has @Entity annotation.

Car is a class I implemented, that also needs to be an entity. The framework, however, keeps track of times of creation and I need to use that information in a query. However, I can't query Vehicle directly because, I need just the cars, not trucks, bikes etc.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `Vehicle` as en entity as you have annotated it with `javax.persistence.Entity` You should not or otherwise you should declare it as an abstract class.

You can also specifying mapped superclasses by annotating the `Vehicle` class with the  `javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass` annotation.

For example :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Vehicle {
    private LocalDateTime dateTimeOfCreation;
}
```

The solution is suitable if you don't want to query Vehicle entities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, unfortunately, in my case it can't be done like that. Please, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

class Vehicle

```
@Entity(name = "vehicle")
    @Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class Vehicle {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        private LocalDateTime dateTimeOfCreation;

        public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }   

        public Date getDateTimeOfCreation() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDateTimeOfCreation(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
```

Class Car:

```
@Entity(name = "car")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
public class Car extends Vehicle {

}
```

Dao class:

```
public class Abc {
  -----your logic-----
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from car as c where c.dateTimeOfCreation >= :date");
        query.setParameter("date", LocalDateTime.now());
        List<RegularEmployee> regularEmployees = query.list();
}
```